# Java using final keyword inside a method

Tags: java, final

In Java, the keyword `final` is used to indicate that the variable cannot be reassigned. If that is the case, why can't a variable declared inside a method have the `final` keyword?  Why is this not legal:

```
public void method()
{ 
  final String x = "name";
}
```

It could come in handy for long methods.

Comment: Uhm, you *can* do that... what's the question?

Comment: This is a great example of why you should actually try things before asking questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can.

```
public void foo() {
    final String bar = "bar";
}
```

Will compile just fine.

Comment: ...and behave just as expected. `bar = "foo";` on a following line will fail to compile. (`final` local variables are also accessible in any anonymous inner classes defined in said local scope, which can be handy.)

Comment: Thank you. My mistake to assume otherwise.